# How do I run and dive in Black Ops?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

For domination games, I see some guys run up to the flag and dive onto it (into a prone position). This is probably really obvious, but I have no idea how they do it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Black-ops added a really cool animation from going from a sprint to a prone position.  In the other call of duty games, this was called a [drop shot](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Drop_Shot). Essentially from a sprint, mash the prone key and your character will 'hit the deck' by diving head first.  It's important to note that you must previously be running, you can't dive standing still even if you hit the sprint button first.

Its really useful when taking fire, escaping grenades, or when you come face to face with an opponent and want to increase your chance of survival (they will have to aim down to hit you and most players have fairly conservative sensitivity)

[Heres how not to dive: 9 second video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KUbeer2oLog)

Comment: Hrm. That's what I tried doing. Does it look the same from your own perspective (for me it just looked like I stopped sprinting and laid down).

Comment: Your character will make a grunt and dive head first.  Try turning during a 'dive', if you can't you probably did it right!

Comment: Ok, I guess I'm just a n00b. Will try it tonight again...

Comment: Good luck and happy knee cap blasting!

Comment: @Michael You have to have a decent bit of speed at the time, otherwise your character will sort of just go to prone.

Comment: @rapida you just mean you have to sprint for a few steps before you dive? i.e. I should just hit the left stick and dive at the same time...

Comment: @Michael thats exactly right, sorry I just assumed.  You have to be sprinting previous to hitting prone which means a few previous steps before it allows you to dive. If your not running you'll just lay down

Comment: @Michael Pretty much, run a bit before diving

Comment: One thing not mentioned yet is that you can also use the action dive to dive through windows, even if they aren't broken yet. This is extremely useful for surprising people or avoiding grenades. There are even a couple challenges for killing people immediately after diving or diving through windows.

Answer (score 2):

Aardvark's answer pretty much explains how to dive. You should also know that while you're in-dive and for about a second or two after hitting the ground (ie. when the animation is playing), you cannot shoot or knife.

Comment: Good point, just another 'balance' feature to make black-ops suck for competitive players lol

Comment: This basically makes drop-shotting very ineffective in many cases.. which I don't have a problem with :) (I usually only drop when I have to reload under fire)

Comment: Its also useful to dive for cover, as you can dive through windows and such